# react-native-swiper doesnt support this.props.navigation.navigate

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo, react-props, react-native-swiper

I am new to react native, I am trying to implement react-native-swiper to my project

```
render() {
    return (
      <Swiper
        loop={false}
        showsPagination={false}
        index={1}>

        <View style={this.viewStyle()}>
          <ActivityScreen />
        </View>

        <Swiper
          horizontal={true}
          loop={false}
          showsPagination={false}
          index={1}>
          
          <View style={this.viewStyle()}>
<YourGroups  />
        </View>
        
        </Swiper>     

          <View style={this.viewStyle()}>
            <AlertScreen />
          </View>

        </Swiper>
      
    )
  }
}
```

But when I am in  component screen and click on the button

```
<Button title="thank you" onPress={()=>this.props.navigation.navigate("ThankScreen")} ></Button>
```

I get an error

> undefined is not an object (evaluating 'this.props.navigation.navigate')

Comment: Can you show the code for that `<Button>`? Which component is it in?

Comment: The <Button> is inside the <YourGroups> component.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in to the same issue and fixed it using React Navigation, 5 which allows you to access the navigation prop from any component using the `useNavigation` hook:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button } from 'react-native';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

const GoToButton = ({ screenName }) => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();

  return (
    <Button
      title={`Go to ${screenName}`}
      onPress={() => navigation.navigate(screenName)}
    />
  );
}
```